# How to deal with this eigen error of static assertion failed?

Tags: c++, class, eigen, eigen3

I'm using vscode to write my cpp code. It use the Eigen package. And I met a strange error:

---

**error**: static assertion failed: YOU_CALLED_A_FIXED_SIZE_METHOD_ON_A_DYNAMIC_SIZE_MATRIX_OR_VECTOR

214 |   EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_FIXED_SIZE(Derived)

```
  |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

I don't know what does it mean.So I ask someone for help. And my code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
class relax{
    public:
        relax(int mn,int mm,double mxmin,double mxmax,double mymin,double mymax,double merror);
        ~relax();
    private:
        int n;
        int m;
        double xmin;
        double xmax;
        double ymin;
        double ymax;
        double error;
        Eigen::MatrixXd U;
        Eigen::MatrixXd U1;
        double rho(int i,int j);
};
relax::relax(int mm,int mn,double mxmin,double mxmax,double mymin,double mymax,double merror){
    xmin=mxmin;
    xmax=mxmax;
    ymin=mymin;
    ymax=mymax;
    m=mm;
    n=mm;
    error=merror;
    U.resize(m+2,n+2);
    U=Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero();
}

relax::~relax(){

}

double relax::rho(int m,int n){
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in Eigen (in fact, I've never used Eigen), but if I had to hazard a guess I would say it's because you used a function that only works on fixed-sized vectors or matrices with a dynamically-sized vector or matrix

Comment: Emm,but as I know,the MatrixXd::Zero() is designed to deal with a dynamic  matrix.@Human-Compiler

Comment: I don't know why. I can't google to find its answer..

Comment: Are you trying to set the matrix to zero? i.e. `U.setZero();`?

Comment: emm,MatrixXd::Zero() only can be used in initialized.@Human-Compiler

Comment: Yeah,it's this problem's answer.@JHBonarius

Comment: Use the member initializer list instead of resizing the matrix: `relax::relax(int mm, int mn, double mxmin, double mxmax, double mymin, double mymax, double merror) : n(mm), m(mm), xmin(mxmin), xmax(mxmax), ymin(mymin), ymax(mymax), error(merror), U(m + 2, n + 2) {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(rows, cols)` can be used to create a matrix initialized to 0.
E.g. `U=Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(m+2,n+2);`

If you already have defined a matrix and want to set it to zero, use the `setZero` function: `U.setZero();`.